# Python: Creating a Unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

I have a problem in Python with Unicode. I need plot a graph with Unicode annotations in it. According to the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/text_intro.html) I should just create my string in Unicode. I do it like this:

```
annotation = u"%s has %s rev"%(art.title, len(art.revisions))
```

It is `art.title` that has Unicode characters in it. Sometimes that code works, sometimes it gives me the error below:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT:
I have error exactly after "annotation" line:

```
  File "script.py", line 195, in test_trie
annotation = u"%s has %s rev"%(art.title, len(art.revisions))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Where is `art.title` coming from?

Comment: Are you sure the error message is given for the code line you gave us? I suspect the error actually occurs when you print out `annotation`. In that case, could you show that code line as well?

Comment: @jogojapan yes, see edit to the question.

Comment: Have you tried `annotation = u"%s has %d rev" % (art.title.decode('utf-8'), len(art.revisions))`, as suggested by Maksym Kozlenko below?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it depends if your title has a unicode characters or not.

I would try adding `art.title.encode("utf-8")` or `art.title.decode("utf-8")` and see how it works

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:  Either use `art.title.decode('utf_8')`, or create a new Unicode string with UTF-8 encoding by `unicode(art.title, 'utf_8')`.

Comment: Those two expressions do the same thing, and the `decode` would be my choice. For a similar situation see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3