# Expected string or buffer Python

Tags: python, string, exception, buffer

I'm really new to python, it's the first time I'm writing it actually.
And I'm creating a program that gets the number of views on a Twitch.tv stream, but I'm getting an error **Expected string or buffer Python** when I'm calling this function

```
 def getURL():
  output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/streamname", "-j"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[1]
  return json.loads(output)["streams"]["worst"]["url"]
```

I'm calling the function from here:

```
urls = []

urls.append(getURL())
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been trying to figure this one out for ages... And if anybody knows how to fix this, I'd be the happiest man alive ;)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is all the code I have.

```
import requests
import subprocess
import json
import sys
import threading
import time

urls = []
urlsUsed = []

def getURL():
output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/hemzk", "-j"],       stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[1]
return json.loads(output)["streams"]["worst"]["url"]

def build():

global numberOfViewers

  urls.append(getURL())
```

And I'm getting the error at **return json.loads(output)["streams"]["worst"]["url"]**

Comment: Post the full code sample and error message and I'll take a look.

Comment: At least say which line the error refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/streamname", "-j"],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[1]
```

to

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["livestreamer", "twitch.tv/streamname", "-j"],
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

(Change 1 to 0).

More detailed explanation of your problem follows.  `Popen.communicate` returns a tuple `stdout, stderr`.  Here, it looks like you are interested in `stdout` (index 0), but you are picking out `stderr` (index 1).  `stderr` is `None` here because you have not attached a pipe to it.  You then try to parse `None` using `json.loads()` which expected a `str` or a `buffer` object.

If you want `stderr` output, you must add `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` to your `Popen` constructor call.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But I'm still getting an error on the same line, but this time, it's a **Can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object**

Comment: Are you using Python 3+?  If so, you must explicitly convert the `bytes` object (your `stdout`) into a string.  For instance: `json.loads(stdout.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010551/how-to-convert-between-bytes-and-strings-in-python-3 for more details