# how to get the string value from numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I store string data as characters in a numpy array, and retrieve the values later, it always returns a value as b'x' for 'x' I stored earlier. Currently I am using the stupid way to extract the value by doing `str(some_array[row, col...]).lstrip("b'").rstrip("'")`, I believe there should be an easier way to do this. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to include code demonstrating the problem. also, what version of python and numpy?

Comment: I found that if I use dtype = 'S', this happens, if I use dtype = str, this doesn't happen. I probably didn't totally comprehend the meaning of these data types...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output you're using Python 3 (where `bytes` and `str` are different types). This answer applies to arrays with `dtype='S'` (a bytestring); for `dtype=str` or `dtype='U'` they are stored as unicode strings (at least for python 3) and there is no issue.

The easiest thing to do is probably

```
str(some_array[row,col...],encoding='ascii')
```

Note that you can use other encodings instead of ascii (`'UTF-8'` is common) and which one is right depends on which one you used to put your data into the numpy array. If you're using non-exotic alphanumeric characters it shouldn't really matter though. If you've put an `str` into the array, numpy uses ascii to encode it, so unless you've gone to special effort to do something different, `'ascii'` should be right.

(For reference, I found this answer helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010552/4657412)