# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface using Python3.x

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I have just migrate from python 2.x to python 3.x and the code below has stopped working.

```
    #self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
    print self.data

    words = self.data.split(',') //the problem seems to be here
```

Any idea how to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `bytes` in python 3 are not same as `str`. What the `request.recv` gives you is a `bytes` of data. You'd need to first convert it to `str` and then use it to `split`.

You can do an `utf-8` decode. So something like -

```
self.data.decode('utf-8').split(',') should work.
```

[How to convert between bytes and strings in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010551/how-to-convert-between-bytes-and-strings-in-python-3) has a more detailed explanation.