# How do you use a variable argument on base64.b64encode but when i am not using the prompt window?

Tags: python, base64, encode

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740188/base64-b64encode-error) one here but if I put this into this code like so:

```
import base64
theone = input('Enter your plaintext: ')
encoded = str(base64.b64encode(theone))
encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded.encode('ascii'))
encoded = encoded[2:]
o = len(encoded)
o = o-1
encoded = encoded[:o]
print(encoded)
```

it raises this problem:

```
line 58, in b64encode
encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

And then if I remove this line of code:

```
encoded = base64.b64encode(encoded.encode('ascii'))
```

then it raises the same error. I'm not sure what to do from here and I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What is `s` in your example?

Comment: Thanks thom that was an error(see edit) but this code still raises the same problems

Comment: The error message says `binascii.b2a_base64`, but that's not in your code. Please make a [mre] including the error message and traceback

Comment: wjandrea I am not entirely sure why it says ```binascii.b2a_base64``` in the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by traceback?

Comment: @Manav The traceback is sort of the history or chain of what function called what function, and where the problem occurred. For more details, see [Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions) in the Python Tutorial. In your case it looks like the error message is missing a few lines from the top, containing the rest of the traceback

Comment: I just realized `binascii.b2a_base64` is called by `b64encode`, that's why it's in the traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be having problems with *bytes* and *strings*.  The value returned by input is a string (`str`), but [base64.b64encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) expects bytes (`bytes`).

If you print a `bytes` instance you see something like

```
b'spam'
```

To remove the leading `'b'` you need to decode back to a `str`.

To make your code work, pass bytes to `base64.b64encode`, and decode the result to print it.

```
>>> theone = input('Enter your plaintext: ')
Enter your plaintext: Hello World!
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(theone.encode())
>>> encoded
b'SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh'
>>> print(encoded.decode())
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
```

Comment: Thanks snakecharmerb that helped me a lot. But I was just wondering why did it say ```binascii.b2a_base64``` in the error text when I did not use the binascii module in my code?(see above question comments)

Comment: Because the base64 module uses functions imported from the binascii module to do the encoding - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/base64.py