# How can we extract elements value if elements attribute is dynamically changing

Tags: css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

How can we extract value by using xpth or css selector if the attribute is dynamically changed for example:

```
<p data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0">
    <b data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.0">Mark Obtain</b>
    <i class="avu-full-width" data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.1">
        <span data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.1.0"> </span>
        <span data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.1.1">450 A+.</span>
    </i>
</p>

<p data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$1">
    <b data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$1.0">Student Name</b>
    <i class="avu-full-width" data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$1.1">
        <span data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.1.0"> </span>
        <span data-reactid=".2e46q6vkxnc.1.$0.1.1">First Name</span>
    </i>
</p>
```

In this case attribute of element is dynamically changing but "Mark Obtain" and "Student Name" will always be same, so is there any way or can we write if condition or some regex along with xpath expression to get "450 A+" and "First Name" values.
Please help

Comment: Show how you tried to solve the issue

Comment: @Andersson unfortunately, I couldn't found the way to extract it. However I tried with response.xpath('//p[b/text=Mark Obtain]/i/span/text()').extract() which seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get required values you can use below XPath expressions:

```
//p[b="Mark Obtain"]//span[2]/text()
```

to get `"450 A+."`

and

```
//p[b="Student Name"]//span[2]/text()
```

to get `"First Name"`

Comment: Thank a lot :)
how can we store the value of this tag<span class="sdr-full-width">हिन्दी</span> that is "हिन्दी" I tried to extract but getting \u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940 unicode characters. please help

Comment: Did you try to add prefix `u` as `print(u"\u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940")`?

Comment: Great! Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: Actually the result of item['Languages'] = response.xpath('//p[span[@data-automation-id="meta-info-languages"]]/b/text()').extract() expression was \u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940, so
where to add u" as a prefix in this expression. Please help

Comment: Before the string: u"string"

Comment: I tried like string = response.xpath('//p[span[@data-automation-id="meta-info-lang‌​uages"]]/b/text()').‌​extract()

u"string" but then I get u'string'

Comment: tried but got \xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa4\xbf\xe0\xa4\xa8\xe0\xa5\x8d\xe0\xa4\xa6\xe0\xa5\x80, this type of encoding.

Comment: Wait. When you just `print(string)` you get desired output? It seem that you don't need decode/encode...

Comment: No, when i just go with print(string) then i get \u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940, which is not required. desired output should be हिन्दी
In IDE when i just use u"\u0939\u093f\u0928\u094d\u0926\u0940"  then i get correct output but i do not to get desired output when i store the result in some variable and then use u"variable"

Comment: Hm... weird. Check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203265/python-string-encoding-for-a-variable). I guess it should help you better