# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface in 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a server in Python. The code is:

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
localHost =  # my address
port = 5369
serverSocket.bind( (localHost, port) )
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
  print ("Ready to serve.....")
  connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

try:
    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    filename = message.split()[1]
    f = open(filename[1:])
    outputdata = f.read()

  for i in range(0, len(outputdata) ):
      connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])

  connectionSocket.close()

except IOError:
    connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found')

connectionSocket.close()
serverSocket.close()
```

I executed the file. It gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File:"D;\.....\server.py", line 25, in <module>
  connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.
```

After scanning through similar queries on Stackoverflow,I found out that from Python 3.0, the data needs to converted to bytes. If that's the case, then where and how should I change/parse the data?

Comment: All those other questions explain that you need to encode your data from a string to bytes. Did you try to apply that yet? What went wrong when you did?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I dunno how to do it. It's my first time with Python.

Comment: See [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7585435), but in this case opening the file in binary mode is easier.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so,I should do this:

    `outputBin = bytes(outputdata,"utf-8")`

and then send outputBin?

Comment: I've already answered below as to what you should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You opened your file in *text mode*, which means that the contents are decoded to unicode strings.

When writing to the socket you need to write `bytes` instead. You can easily get bytes from a file by opening it in binary mode instead:

```
with open(filename[1:], 'rb') as f:
    connectionSocket.send(f.read())
```

Note that I send the data to the socket *in one go*; no need to send the data byte by byte here.

Answer (score 0):

Method send() accepts argument of binnary format. So try to use method encode('utf-8') to send some data to server:

```
connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode('utf-8'))
```

And use decode('utf-8') to get string from the data that method recv() returns.