# Python3:socket:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'bytes'

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I am try to use python `socket` package to implement an echo  server. But it continuously occurs the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'bytes'`, is there any errors in my code?

here is the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 869, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "do_tcp_server.py", line 25, in tcplink
        sock.send(b'Hello, %s!' % data)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

Here is my code:

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

"A simple server"

import socket
import threading
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 9999))

s.listen(5)
print("Lsitening...")

def tcplink(sock, addr):
    print('Accept new connection from %s:%s...' % addr)
    sock.send(b'Welcome!')
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        time.sleep(1)
        if not data or data.decode('utf-8') == 'exit':
            break
        sock.send(b'Hello, %s!' % data)
    sock.close()
    print('Connection from %s:%s closed.' % addr)

while True:
    sock, addr = s.accept()
    # create a thread to handle it
    t = threading.Thread(target=tcplink, args=(sock, addr))
    t.start()
```

client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# establish connection:
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9999))
# receive Welcome data:
print(s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
for data in [b'Michael', b'Tracy', b'Sarah']:
    # send data
    s.send(data)
    print(s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
s.send(b'exit')
s.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal string formatting cannot be used for `bytes`. I think the way to go about it is - you'd have to first generate a string, format it and then convert it to bytes with appropriate encoding. So the following changes should work

change

```
sock.send(b'Hello %s!' % data)
```

to

```
reply = 'Hello %s!' % data) 
sock.send(bytes(reply, 'utf-8'))
```

Basically this is due to difference between string and bytes in python3. [[Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3]) has got some more details about it.

That should work.

Comment: But i still have a question about it, since I send bytes in client.py, why doesn't it works?

Comment: Well - you are directly generating the bytes object when you say b'Tracy' if you try to do something like b'trac%' % 'y', you'd still face the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Acturally this error only occurs on Python 3.4 , I found Python 3.5+ pass it via Travis CI. So for Python 3.4 and Python 2.7:

change

```
sock.send(b'Hello %s!' % data)
```

to

```
reply = 'Hello %s!' % data) 
sock.send(reply.encode('utf-8'))
```

Both Python 2 and Python 3 support `s.encode('utf-8')`

see  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269679/12074740

Note: `bytes(reply, 'utf-8')` is not supported on Python 2

I hope it helps someone like me who wants codes to work on both Python 2 and Python 3

Answer (score 0):

The answer @gaabhijit gaves is good.I only to suppose the code in question is from here([enter link description here](http://www.liaoxuefeng.com/wiki/0014316089557264a6b348958f449949df42a6d3a2e542c000/001432004374523e495f640612f4b08975398796939ec3c000))
Otherwise,when python_3.5 comes,`b'%s'` can be right().