# How to use SHA256-HMAC in python code?

Tags: python, oauth, sha256, hmac

[I am taking message and key from this URL](https://doc.periscopedata.com/doc/embed-api)

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
my = "/api/embedded_dashboard?data=%7B%22dashboard%22%3A7863%2C%22embed%22%3A%22v2%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Filter1%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22value1%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Filter2%22%2C%22value%22%3A%221234%22%7D%5D%7D"
key = "e179017a-62b0-4996-8a38-e91aa9f1"
print(hashlib.sha256(my + key).hexdigest())
```

I am getting this result:

```
2df1d58a56198b2a9267a9955c31291cd454bdb3089a7c42f5d439bbacfb3b88
```

Expecting result:

```
adcb671e8e24572464c31e8f9ffc5f638ab302a0b673f72554d3cff96a692740
```

Comment: You used this for periscope-data embed api right?

Comment: Similar question but sufficient answers here I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910845/generate-hmac-sha256-signature-python

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are not making use of `hmac` at all in your code.

Typical way to use `hmac`, construct an HMAC object from your key, message and identify the hashing algorithm by passing in its constructor:

```
h = hmac.new( key, my, hashlib.sha256 )
print( h.hexdigest() )
```

That should output

```
adcb671e8e24572464c31e8f9ffc5f638ab302a0b673f72554d3cff96a692740
```

for your example data.

Comment: ```h = hmac.new(base64.b32encode(key), my, hashlibsha256)``` to make sure that key is always valid bas32 encoded string.

Answer (score 40):

For later versions of python, you need a mix of all of the other answers to get the OPs output. The `hmac.new` function wants the `key` argument to be of type `bytes` or `bytearray`, so running the code in [Neil Slater's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39767589/8213085) would produce the following error:

> TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

Even if the `key` argument were fixed, the `hmac.new` function would then complain about the `my` string with the following error:

> TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

To fix both of these, the `encode` method from [Wilson Wu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51861438/8213085) is used to convert the variables into the correct types.

```
import hashlib
import hmac

# Define my and key as per question
my = "/api/embedded_dashboard?data=%7B%22dashboard%22%3A7863%2C%22embed%22%3A%22v2%22%2C%22filters%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22Filter1%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22value1%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22Filter2%22%2C%22value%22%3A%221234%22%7D%5D%7D"
key = "e179017a-62b0-4996-8a38-e91aa9f1"

# Encode as per other answers
byte_key = key.encode("UTF-8")
message = my.encode()

# Now use the hmac.new function and the hexdigest method
h = hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Print the output
print(h)
```

The output that this prints is

```
adcb671e8e24572464c31e8f9ffc5f638ab302a0b673f72554d3cff96a692740
```

exactly as the OP expected.

Comment: Thank you for the compilation. I tested this with Python 3.11.5 and it works fine. I think a more specific wording instead of *later versions of Python* would make this answer even better. In my opinion, it would also be better to consistently use either `bytes()` or `str.encode()`. I would lean towards `encode` here, but it might be better to read [some arguments from Python professionals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7585435/2932052).

Comment: @Wolf -- totally agree with both comments! I've updated the answer to use `str.encode()` consistently, but I don't actually know which version this is correct from hence the ambiguity (I would prefer to put an actual version)

Answer (score 8):

Some code for you, easy to use:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import binascii

def create_sha256_signature(key, message):
    byte_key = binascii.unhexlify(key)
    message = message.encode()
    return hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

create_sha256_signature("E49756B4C8FAB4E48222A3E7F3B97CC3", "TEST STRING")
```

Answer (score 1):

A note to Wilson WU's answer, if both the key and messages are hex, the returned value is wrong, just change below line of code to fix that ;

message = message.encode() --->  message = message.binascii.unhexlify(message)

Comment: also is only the key is in hex you need unhexify. thanks for this.  spend days on it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late. Yet, posting what worked for me just in case it works for someone else -

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

access_token = <your token in string format>
app_secret = <your secret access key in string format>

# use any one, all three options work.
# OPTION 1 (it works)
# digest = hmac.new(app_secret.encode('UTF-8'),
#                   access_token.encode('UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256)
# OPTION 2 (it works)
# digest = hmac.new(str.encode(app_secret),
#                   str.encode(access_token), hashlib.sha256)
# OPTION 3 (it works)
digest = hmac.new(bytes(app_secret, 'UTF-8'),
                bytes(access_token, 'UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256)
signature = digest.hexdigest()
print(signature)
```