# Generate HMAC SHA256 signature Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hmac

Trying to generate HMAC SHA256 signature for 3Commas, I use the same parameters from the [official example](https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#example-1-as-a-query-string), it should generate:
"30f678a157230290e00475cfffccbc92ae3659d94c145a2c0e9d0fa28f41c11a"

But I generate:
"17a656c7df48fa2db615bfc719627fc94e59265e6af18cc7714694ea5b58a11a"

Here is what I tried:

```
secretkey = 'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j'
totalParams = '/public/api/ver1/accounts/new?type=binance&name=binance_account&api_key=XXXXXX&secret=YYYYYY'
print 'signature = '+hashlib.sha256((secretkey+totalParams).encode('ASCII')).hexdigest()
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Same question, more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767297/how-to-use-sha256-hmac-in-python-code

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try using the [`hmac`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new) module instead of the `hashlib` module:

```py
import hmac
import hashlib


secret_key = b"NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
total_params = b"/public/api/ver1/accounts/new?type=binance&name=binance_account&api_key=XXXXXX&secret=YYYYYY"
signature = hmac.new(secret_key, total_params, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print("signature = {0}".format(signature))
```

This gives the desired result:

```
signature = 30f678a157230290e00475cfffccbc92ae3659d94c145a2c0e9d0fa28f41c11a
```

### Edit

Note that the `hmac` module accepts bytes for the key and message. If your inputs are strings, you can use the [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) method with the relevant character set, e.g. `'ascii'`, `'utf-8`' (default), [etc.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

In the above code example I am using the [bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) introduced in [PEP-3112](https://peps.python.org/pep-3112/). A bytes literal can only contain ASCII characters, anything outside of the range of ASCII must be entered as the relevant escape sequences.

For example:

```py
emoji = b'\xf0\x9f\x98\x84'
print(emoji.decode('utf-8'))
```

Therefore, the following line from the code example above...

```py
secret_key = b"NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
```

...is equivalent to:

```py
secret_key = "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j".encode('ascii')
```

Comment: Why do you have 'b' before the variable. Like so `secret_key = b"`

Comment: I'm using a bytes literal, which is effectively the equivalent of writing `''.encode('ASCII')` but without creating the intermediate string. As the hmac.new method call accepts bytes as its params. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects

Comment: Maybe the information about [byte literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings) should be included in the answer as well as a word about applicability: In case you are using a key or message outside 7-bit ASCII, you need to switch to something like `str.encode('UTF-8')`.

Answer (score 0):

I did implement it using a different approach few years ago.

```
import hmac
import hashlib 
import binascii

def create_sha256_signature(key, message):
    byte_key = binascii.unhexlify(key)
    message = message.encode()
    return hmac.new(byte_key, message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

create_sha256_signature("E49756B4C8FAB4E48222A3E7F3B97CC3", "TEST STRING")
```

https://www.gauravvjn.com/generate-hmac-sha256-signature-in-python/