# python3 decode external utf8 string

Tags: python, utf-8

Suppose I have the following string that I want to decode as utf-8:

```
str ='\\u00d7\\u0090\\u00d7\\u0090\\u00d7\\u0090'
# expect 'אאא'
```

Using python 3, I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
bytes(str, 'ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
# prints '×××'
bytes(str, 'ascii').decode('utf-8')
# prints '\\u00d7\\u0090\\u00d7\\u0090\\u00d7\\u0090'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with multiple trips through `encode`/`decode`.

```
print(st.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

The first is [the preferred alternate to `bytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3). The second converts the escape sequences to their equivalent characters. The third takes advantage of Unicode being based on ISO-8859-1 for the first 256 code points to convert those characters directly back into bytes. Finally you can decode the UTF-8 string.