# How to convert a string into bytes using bytes() in Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I need a little help with the `bytes();`function in Python 3.5.
I hope I understand this properly, but bytes are a different way of storing a value, like `52` is `110100`in binary. (Except binary is in bits right?) Anyway can somebody please tell me the following:

- The proper syntax of `bytes();`(In use of a string)
- Proper arguments the parameter "encoding" in `bytes(str,encoding);`
- If I am completely mis-using this concept please tell me.

### NOTE:

I am using this for weak cryptographic purposes. Please tell me how to:

> Add a constant to every byte

And how to reverse aforesaid process.

### How I am Using It:

```
str = "MyString";
data = bytes(str,*WHAT GOES HERE*);
print(data);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell if you're misusing the concept, since you don't show how you're using it.  If you want basic info on how to use `bytes` you should read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes).  Otherwise, you should show a code example with an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish using `bytes`, and why it's not working as you planned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: `bytes("Hello World!", "utf-8")`

Comment: BTW: Python doesn't need `;`

Comment: @furas I need something that makes it harder to read from a file.

Comment: @furas I know about the `;` its force of habit.

Comment: `bytes("ąśćłó", "utf-8")`

Comment: Ok, heres how I want my program to flow: Get input, convert to bytes, add a constant to every byte, close file end program.

Comment: have you tried `codecs.encode("hello world","rot-13")` ?

Answer (score 0):

By importing `codecs` I can encode and decode it easily! Thanks @Jean-François Fabre!

```
import codecs
str = "Done!";
codecs.encode(str,"rot-13")
```