# Python 3.6.1 | Regex Search on files with special characters

Tags: python, regex, search, mmap

***What I intend to do ?***

To perform a search for list of *alphabetic* string among a set of files on Windows File System (around 25K numbers of varying sizes and extensions primarily flat text files, biggest file being not more than few MB in size)

***What I                                                                                  did to achieve this?***

```
for each_file in files:
    file_read_handle = open(each_file,"rb")
    file_read_handle.seek(0) #ensure you're at the start of the file
    first_char = file_read_handle.read(1) #get the first character
    if first_char:
        file_read_content_mappd = mmap.mmap(file_read_handle.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        if re.search(br'(?i)T_0008X_WEB', file_read_content_mappd):
            file_write_content = ('Text T_0008X_WEB found in {}'.format(each_file))
            file_write_handle.write(file_write_content)     
            file_write_handle.write("\n")
file_write_handle.close()
```

This piece of code *works just fine* for **hardcoded** text search (see line T_0008X_WEB) among files that are opened in binary mode ***("rb")*** to avoid *UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 776: character maps to undefined* error.

However, when trying to search a ***list of values*** by replacing the hardcoded value with a variable like this-`if re.search('br\'(?i)' + regex_search_str_byte + '\'', file_read_content_mappd):`, have been facing following issues-

1. When used: `re.search('br\'(?i)' + regex_search_str + '\'', file_read_content_mappd):` got error: *File is in binary and search text is in string type*
2. When used: `re.search(regex_search_str_byte, file_read_content_mappd):` got issue: *No match was found because even the regex characters* **br'(?i)** *were also considered as part of byte converted search text*

Request guidance on ***how to perform byte converted text regex search for a list of values, on binary mode opened file read?***

Comment: Looks like you need `if re.search(str.encode(regex_search_str), file_read_content_mappd)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: In such case, how should we include the regex flag **br'(?i)** ? Have tried to do the same in case 2 mentioned in question, like, Tried to hold the _entire value including regex flags_ into the variable _regex_search_str_ and converted that string to byte and saved in _regex_search_str_byte_. I think you are suggesting the same with string encode to UTF-8 option, however, in this case it returned no match and I suppose the byte converted search text also considered the regex flags to be part of the search text. Suggestions specific to this would be more helpful.

Comment: `if re.search(str.encode(regex_search_str), file_read_content_mappd, flags=re.I)`. The flag can be passed as an argument to the `re.search` method. `br` are not necessary since they are used to modify a string literal, and you are using a variable. I assume `regex_search_str` is  a UTF8 string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3).

Comment: How did you create/assign `regex_search_str_byte`?

Comment: `regex_search_str_byte = bytes(each_string, 'utf-8')`. _each_string_ is an element of another python list of alphanumeric characters

Comment: Ok, does `re.search(regex_search_str_byte, file_read_content_mappd, flags=re.I)` find any matches?

Comment: Thanks for the `flags=re.I` option to replace **(?i)** in my search. Also, could you please let know if there is a similar option for **br'** as well (perform binary text search)

Comment: Working with this `re.search(regex_search_str_byte, file_read_content_mappd, flags=re.I)` now and will update in few mins.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by *similar option for br'*: these prefixes are just string literal modifiers, they are no performing any search.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew , your suggestion to use **flags=re.I** helped. I misunderstood on the string literal modifiers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : You may please post your suggestion as an answer so that I could accept it. Thanks and have a good day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.search(regex_search_str_byte, file_read_content_mappd, flags=re.I)
```

The `re.I` flag can be passed as an argument to the `re.search` method. `br` prefixes are not necessary since they are used to modify a string literal, and you are using a variable.