# Difference between bytes.fromhex() and encode()

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

`key = '140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14' # hex-encoded`

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(key)
b'\x14\x0bA\xb2*)\xbe\xb4\x06\x1b\xdaf\xb6t~\x14'
```

This seems to be correct as the code which I wrote for CBC (cipher) works after this.

The code below was inspired from [this site.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

```
>>> "".join([chr(int(key[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0,len(key),2)]).encode()
b'\x14\x0bA\xc2\xb2*)\xc2\xbe\xc2\xb4\x06\x1b\xc3\x9af\xc2\xb6t~\x14'
```

So, my question is: Why is the output different in both the cases and more importantly how come the length has increased from 16 bytes to 21 bytes in the 2nd case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encoded the *text* representation of the hex values to UTF-8 (the default encoding if you don't specify one). For example, the B2 hex value is converted to a Unicode codepoint U+00B2, which encodes to UTF-8 as C2 B2.

You need to encode as Latin-1 if you want matching bytes for the Unicode codepoints:

```
>>> "".join([chr(int(key[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0,len(key),2)]).encode('latin1')
b'\x14\x0bA\xb2*)\xbe\xb4\x06\x1b\xdaf\xb6t~\x14'
```

The first 256 codepoints of Unicode correspond with the Latin-1 standard, so U+00B2 encodes directly to B2 in binary.

If you wanted to convert hex bytes to integers, do not create Unicode text. Just pass the integers directly to `bytes`:

```
>>> bytes(int(key[i:i + 2], 16) for i in range(0, len(key), 2))
b'\x14\x0bA\xb2*)\xbe\xb4\x06\x1b\xdaf\xb6t~\x14'
```

That way you don't have to translate back from Unicode to bytes.

Comment: Can you point me towards how *B2 hex value is converted to a Unicode codepoint U+00B2*? I think this is all I need to understand.

Comment: @Miraj50: `chr()` produces Unicode text, not bytes. So `chr(int('B2', 16))` produces a Unicode character that in the Unicode standard is referred to as [U+00B2 SUPERSCRIPT TWO](https://codepoints.net/U+00B2).