# Send string to URL (target IP)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, url, python-requests

I have a string URL that I want to send or "post" to a target IP.

I've tried using the requests library but I keep getting errors.

```
import requests
data = {'http://192.168.0.1/mobile/write.fcgi?
serverId=1'}
r = requests.post('http://192.168.0.1', data=data)
```

The error says a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.

How can I send this string to the IP 192.168.0.1 (local host): http://192.168.0.1/mobile/write.fcgi?serverId=1

Comment: You need to encode it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: Your data is  a set (should be dict or str)

Comment: Going out on a limb here without enough info, but I suspect you want `data = {'serverId': '1'}` / `r = requests.get('http://192.168.0.1/mobile/write.fcgi', params=data)`

Comment: "Can the controller send to a defined target IP address the following string whenever a fence is triggered: “http://<localhost>/mobile/write.fcgi?serverId=1&pin=82&status=1” "

I have the code setup to read when an alarm goes off, then when alarm = True I need to send the above string (url) to a target IP.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a b before the string in the data variable should fix this.

```
import requests
data = {b'http://192.168.0.1/mobile/write.fcgi?serverId=1'}
r = requests.post('http://192.168.0.1', data=data)
```

---

Edit: Seeing the comments I might be wrong, but testing the code with a different website gave a response [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qiEt.png)

Edit 2: Checked the `r.content` and it gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujhTu.png), which is a 405 error [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah63q.png). A 405 error simply means that [the script doesn't have the necessary permissions (on the target website) to use the post function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2240K.png)