# How to specify a byte-array serializer/deserializer in Kafka-Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

There is an `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer` class in Kafka's Producer API for Java and a `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer` for the Consumer API.

Are there equivalent classes if you're working with Kafka in Python?

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Answer (score 5):

There's no built-in byte-array serializer/deserializer for Python, but it's not hard to implement. If, for instance, you want to convert a string to its underlying hexadecimal representation in your producer you can implement it this way:

```
KafkaProducer(value_serializer=lambda v: binascii.hexlify(v.encode('utf-8')))
```

If, on the other hand, you had incoming bytes in your consumer and wanted to convert them into their string representation, you could do it like this.

```
KafkaConsumer(value_deserializer=lambda v: binascii.unhexlify(a).decode('utf-8'))
```

Answers are for Python 3+.