# Getting error in my code TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I don't had a much knowledge of python please help me. I am not able to download the tweets the CSV file is generating but its empty. I am not able to get the tweets data onto it! The output is showing that is tweets are downloaded but the data is not taking string format I guess! Please help!

```
import tweepy 
import csv


def get_all_tweets(screen_name):       
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)                
    alltweets = []            

    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)                
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)                
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print ("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)                        
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1            
        print ("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8"),tweet.retweet_count,tweet.favorite_count] for tweet in alltweets]

    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)            
        writer.writerow(["id", "created_at", "text", "retweet_count", "favorite_count"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)        
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    get_all_tweets("Iamrajakaditya")
```

The error I am getting in above code is:

> writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text","retweet_count","favorite_count"])
>   TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message in your question.

Comment: Do you want to convert the `str` to `bytes`?

Comment: Also, statement `pass` is doing exactly nothing. You do not need it.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3).

Comment: @user202729 yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not open the CSV file in the binary mode.

```
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
```

must be:

```
with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
```