# Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code - virtual environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using Mac Anaconda. And I try to use the AES of Crypto. However, I face a strange problem.

I just want to excute a simple line of code:

```
 obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
```

if I run the code without the virtual environment as below it is OK.

```
$ python

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES

>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
```

if I run with the virtual environment "testaes" then I got the error:

```
(testaes)$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 12 2018, 20:05:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES

>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/testaes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 200, in new
return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/testaes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py", line 55, in _create_cipher
return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/testaes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 234, in _create_cbc_cipher
cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/testaes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/AES.py", line 100, in _create_base_cipher
result = start_operation(c_uint8_ptr(key),
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/testaes/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 109, in c_uint8_ptr
raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

You can see that at both time I use the the same Anaconda Python 3.6.4 and GCC4.2.1. How to solve this?

Comment: You can't encrypt text, only bytes.

Comment: I think you should look to the last line of the traceback. See if encoding your string as bytes work.

Comment: What is `Crypto.version_info` in both cases?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Python 3, encode it into a `bytearray`:

```py
obj = AES.new('This is a key123'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456'.encode("utf8"))
```

If you store these in variables and want to use them as (Python) strings again, just use:

```py
key_as_bytearray.decode("utf8")
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7585619/9760446) for further information.

Comment: If this is indeed the problem `b"This is a key123"` without any encoding step would work as well.

Comment: Thank you. It solves this problem. I did try encode("utf8) with the key, but I did not encode the IV.

Comment: @geenFrog if it's just ascii text then `b"myIV"` will work fine, this is just in case you use other chars/encoding

Answer (score 2):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def encrypt(text):  
    private_key = "xxx".encode('utf-8')   
    iv = "yyy".encode('utf-8')
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    pad = lambda s: s + (16 - len(s) % 16) * chr(16 - len(s) % 16)
    encrypted =  base64.b64encode( cipher.encrypt(pad(text)))
    return encrypted.decode("utf-8")
```

This was working fine in Google Collab but It was not showing this above error in Python3 Terminal in Linux. So What I did is -

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

def encrypt(text):
    private_key = bytes("xxx", 'utf-8')
    iv = bytes("yyy", 'utf-8')
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(pad(text.encode("UTF-8"), AES.block_size))
    return b64encode(encrypted).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just encode the key and you will get no error:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

key = ''

cipher_text = ''
cipher_text = base64.b64decode(cipher_text)


decipher = AES.new(key.encode(), AES.MODE_ECB)

print(decipher.decrypt(cipher_text))
```

Answer (score -10):

Python has package named pycryptodome which causes this error.just uninstall the package

sudo pip3 uninstall pycryptodome

Comment: Hi Saurabh, please familiarise yourself with [writing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next one! Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Comment: This is not an answer because the question is not about the library this answer mentions.

Comment: To add context, pycryptodome requires bytes to be passed in https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/issues/488 -- pycrypto does not. Highly recommend not uninstalling pycryptodome and instead passing in bytes, as pycrypto has security issues.