# how can I convert a 'hello world' to b'hello world'

Tags: python

I want to convert a string

```
'hello world'
```

to

```
b'hello world'
```

in python, how can I do that?

Comment: Variable.encode() to form a bytes string and variable.decode('utf-8') to convert bytes to string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.encode()` method to convert a string to bytes.

```
>>> 'hello world'.encode()
b'hello world'
>>>
```

Please refer to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Answer (score 0):

You can use `b = bytes(mystring, 'utf-8')` notation to turn your string into bytes object. But there are many similar questions and related answers in stackoverflow to your question. You should have searched for your question first.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> """b'hello world'"""
b'hello world'
```