# string - Python 3.5 write a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: string, python-3.x, types

My following python code works for Python 2,

#### Write header only once

```
if header_written == False:
    header = out_data.keys()
    writer.writerow(out_data.keys()) # write headers
    header_written = True
```

#### Write values

```
writer.writerow(out_data.values()) #write rows
del out_data  #del object
del row_data #del dict object
```

but in Python 3, it returns the following error:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 14):

You have to convert it to bytes. You can do it like this.

```
bytes = string.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

More info here

[Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: Thanks! I changed 3rd row of first part to: `writer.writerow(out_data.keys().encode('utf-8'))`  But the following error message shows: **'odict_keys' object has no attribute 'encode'**

Answer (score 11):

It is about the initial part.

Change

```
with open('r2.csv', 'r') as infile , open("output2.csv",'wb') as resultFile:
```

To

```
with open('r2.csv', 'r') as infile , open("output2.csv",'w') as resultFile:
```