# byte-variable interpolation in a string

Tags: python, byte

```
with s:
    message = pyautogui.prompt('enter data', 'Send Data')
    s.sendall(**b'variable goes here'**)
    data = s.recv(1024)
```

In line 3, I need to put a variable inside of the parentheses, but keep the bytes prefix, or an equivalent, something like this:

```
s.sendall(b'somerandomtext{variable}')
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with following step:

```
var = "dynamic"

msg = "this is a {} message".format(var)

bytMsg = msg.encode('utf-8')

s.sendall(bytMsg)
```