# How do I encrypt a string variable using Fernet encryption

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Hello I am trying to encrypt this variable using the Fernet method from the cryptogrphy module.

```
MedicalInfo=("Garlic Phobia")
EcryptMedInfo= Ecy.encrypt(MedicalInfo)
print(EcryptMedInfo)
```

However I keep receiving this error message:

```
TypeError: data must be bytes.
```

Comment: "Garlic Phobia" is a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
MedicalInfo=("Garlic Phobia")
b = bytes(MedicalInfo, 'utf-8')
EcryptMedInfo= Ecy.encrypt(b)
print(EcryptMedInfo)
```