# How do I change a string to a bytes-like object?

Tags: python, string, encode

I am following a Machine Learning tutorial (from a text book) and I got stuck on a portion of the code I was given and I am not sure how to proceed. It seems as though I need to change the data type of object to a "bytes-like" as opposed to a string.

I have tried adding a line changing "name" to encode utf-8

```
for line in data:
    if firstLine:
        names = line.strip().split(";")
        firstLine = False
    else:
    ...
```

The error I receive:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I am trying to understand why the data-type must be changed, and how I can change it.

Comment: You haven't provided us enough detail to answer why the data-type must be changed, as this depends on the library and API you are using. To convert a `str` to `bytes` use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode), if you are already doing this then perhaps you have mistaken where your error is - provide the exception details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: Let me guess, python 2.7? Reading from a csv? Those questions usually start like this.

Comment: Sorry! First time poster here. I am using Python3 on Spyder. And yes, I am trying to read from a CSV

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Are you opening your file in binary mode?

Comment: The error message implies that `names` is a byte string, which means the parameter to `split` must also be a byte string: `b";"`.