# How to input audio as bytes in moviepy

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, audio, boto3, audio-streaming

I have audio as bytes in the form of:

```
b'ID3\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00#TSSE\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x03Lavf57.71.100\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\...
```

That I got from Amazon web services:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('polly')
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    Engine='neural',
    LanguageCode='en-GB',
    OutputFormat='mp3',
    SampleRate='8000',
    Text='hey whats up this is a test',
    VoiceId='Brian'
)
```

And I want to input it into moviepy audiofile using

```
AudioFileClip()
```

AudioFileClip takes filename or an array representing a sound. I know I can save the audio as a file and read it, but I would like to have AudioFileClip take the bytes output I showed above.

I tried:

```
AudioFileClip(response['AudioStream'].read())
```

But this gives the error:

> TypeError: endswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not
>   str

What can I do?

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert the stream of audio to a different type. (Thats why its called TypeError). You are putting it as a string and it wants a byte format.

You can convert a str to a byte by using the bytearrayfunction!
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray

You can also look at this question:
[Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

For more help just comment on this anwser, and Ill try to help you as soon as possible.

Hope this can help you on your project,

PythonMasterLua

Comment: But the output of response['AudioStream'].read() is b'ID3\x04\x00\x0... which is bytes type. Im not inputting a string.

Comment: The code is thinking you are inputting a str, so you have to do the function above.