# python3 convert string to io.BytesIO

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to insert a file to mysql server by sending a `io.BytesIO()` object in a `blob` datatype, then send the file back to my client.
however my client receives a `str` class instead of the actual `io.BytesIO()` class

so instead of receiving `<_io.BytesIO object as 0X7....>`
I receive `"<_io.BytesIO object as 0X7....>"`.

is there anyway of converting `str` to `BytesIO`?

Comment: How are you creating the BytesIO object, and how are you passing it to MySQL? Please edit your question to show your code.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Comment: `BytesIO.getbuffer()` to obtain the underlying buffer?