# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' when I'm inputting command in console

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I'm trying to connect to a server using socket module in python. However, I get an error message as shown below.

```py
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Here's my code:

```py
import socket
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 12345

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))


server_socket.listen(5)
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(PORT)+ ", waiting for connexions. ")


client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected \n")


while True:
    try:
        command = input(client_ip+ ">")
        if(len(command.split()) != 0):
            client_socket.send(command)

        else:
            continue

    except(EOFError):
        print("Invalid input, type 'help' to get a list of implented commands. \n")

        continue

    if(command == "quit"):
        break


    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(data + "\n")


client_socket.close()
```

What causes this TypeError? and what should I do to fix this ?.
I'm also open to any advice to improve my python socket code writing.

Comment: When you say 'better' how exactly do you mean? Could you also post more of your error log to identify which line is having the problem. 

I'd assume when you type client_socket.send(command) is your issue for the bytes like object, try client_socket.send(bytes(command))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: So now its TypeError: string argument without an encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because python expects bytes not string to be sent via socket.
Hence you have to convert strings to bytes before sending that. you can use `encode()` to convert string to bytes and use `decode()` to convert bytes received into string.
I have updated your code, Please refer below, this should work fine.

```py
import socket
HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 12345

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))


server_socket.listen(5)
print("\n[*] Listening on port " +str(PORT)+ ", waiting for connexions. ")


client_socket, (client_ip, client_port) = server_socket.accept()
print("[*] Client " +client_ip+ " connected \n")


while True:
    try:
        command = input(client_ip+ ">")
        if(len(command.split()) != 0):
            client_socket.send(command.encode('utf-8')) #Encoding required here

        else:
            continue

    except(EOFError):
        print("Invalid input, type 'help' to get a list of implented commands. \n")

        continue

    if(command == "quit"):
        break


    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode('utf-8') + "\n") #Decoding required here


client_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

easily, just convert the string to a byte-wise object with

```
string = "example string"
byte_wise_string = string.encode("utf-8")
```

Hope I could help

Greets

Comment: Where do i implement this?

Comment: client_socket.send() takes an byte-wise-element as parameter so you should add an .encode("utf-8") to the command variable

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.socket.send

You'd want to

- [`encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20encode#str.encode) the string to byte object before sending: `client_socket.send(command.encode())`
- and [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20encode#bytes.decode) back to string when you concatenate in print: `print(data.decode() + "\n")`