# How to send a hexcode string in SOCKET python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I tried to send a hexcode string using the `socket` module in python. I wrote the following:

```
import socket
HOST = '192.168.140.2' 
PORT = 55000 
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
s.connect((HOST, PORT))   
  while True: 
      DATA = '\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff   \x00\xff\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00'
      s.sendall(DATA) 
      data = s.recv(4096)
      s.close()
```

But it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Python\echo-client.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.sendall(DATA)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

When I send a single hexcode, using `s.sendall(b'\xff')`, it works.

How can I send a hex string to a server?

Comment: Probably your answer is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `b` before the string in the `DATA` variable. It is required to make it a `bytes` object instead of a `str` object, which is accepted by `socket.socket.sendall()`.

Comment: Thanks. it works. but I am struggling to stop from data sending...

Comment: @RabiulIslam just break out of the while loop when ur done sending data