# Using b'' like f string in python

Tags: python, byte, encode

I have this string `s = 'ha\xcc\x81nh'`. I want to use as byte, is there anything as `b'{s}'` like f string `f'{s}'`

Comment: Would this question help you out? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

Normally we can use the following code to convert a string to a byte string.

```
b = sample_string.encode()
```

If we use this method in your use-case it would be like this.

```
b = f'{s}'.encode()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite sad that Python developers are quite narrow-minded and stubborn, that they refuse to offer the bytes-version for f-string (https://python-forum.io/thread-28345.html ).

However, I do encounter many cases where I need to use f-string for bytes. For example, for smart-home IoT automation, I need to send `b'\x82\x99\x01\x00\x01\x00"438/E1G-SG-NGA0301A/status/current\x01\x00#438/E1G-SG-NGA0301A/status/software\x01\x00%438/E1G-SG-NGA0301A/status/connection\x01\x00!438/E1G-SG-NGA0301A/status/faults\x01'` to the Dyson Fan, where `E1G-SG-NGA0301A` is the Fan's serial number which has appeared 4 times.

Simple strings can use `.encode()` or `.decode()` to convert between `bytes` and `str`. For the above bytes sequence, `.decode()` does not work, i.e.,

```
'\x82\x99\x01\x00\x01\x00"438'.encode() == b'\x82\x99\x01\x00\x01\x00"438'
False
```

In fact, this bytes sequence is not in UTF-8, `.decode().encode()` will give an error. So the above method that first use f-string then do `.encode()` will not work in my case.

Similar arbitrary and inferior decisions are made on the `range()` function. Where we have to use `list(range(100))` in Python3 instead of `range(100)` in Python2 (which is much faster and simpler). They do not foresee the case where sometimes we need to create a ranged list for index sorting, etc, in which an iterator does not work. The only thing that comes to their mind is `for i in range(100)`.

In conclusion, f-string for bytes is useful; both iterator-version `range` and list-version `range` are useful. If the Python language decision makers keeps being stubborn and self-centered as such, we will see little hope in this language in the future.

Comment: You can use %-interpolation like: `b'\x82\x99\x01\x00\x01\x00"438/%b' % b'E1G-SG-NGA0301A'` as described in [PEP 461](https://peps.python.org/pep-0461/). Also other than the first paragraph which can be considered an answer the remaining paragraphs aren't really useful in an answer on Stack Overflow, if you have any suggestions how Python should work take those to the appropriate place for those.

Comment: Yup, but the problem is that there are 4 occurrences and I have to put down `%s` and the string 4 times each. Or should I use `.replace()`?

Comment: You can obviously put `b'E1G-SG-NGA0301A'` into a variable and use that, also you can do something like `b'1%(sr_no)b2%(sr_no)b3%(sr_no)b4%(sr_no)b' % {b'sr_no': b'E1G-SG-NGA0301A'}`