# Convert list of string into byte array with the same length using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = ['67', '56', '23', '29', '5e', 'eb', '6f', 'c9', 'dc', 'dd', '24', '1b', '00', 'b7', '6b', '69', 'e0', 'ce', 'c9', '2c', '61', '18', '22', '10', 'cb', 'a6', 'd5', '82', 'b2', '5d', 'ef', '32']
```

Length of a is `32`

is there any way to convert above string  into bytes format with the same length. i need answer same like below

```
a = [b'67', '56', '23', '29', '5e', 'eb', '6f', 'c9', 'dc', 'dd', '24', '1b', '00', 'b7', '6b', '69', 'e0', 'ce', 'c9', '2c', '61', '18', '22', '10', 'cb', 'a6', 'd5', '82', 'b2', '5d', 'ef', '32']
```

Comment: `a = [s.encode() for s in a]` or `a = list(map(str.encode, a))` should both work. But why would you want `b'67'` instead of `b'\x67'` as your result?

Comment: Thanks @kaya3, It's working, may be my requirement was wrong, Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @kaya3, maybe you should post your comments as an answer so it gets accepted. Otherwise, this will stay open :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: @JoeFerndz I was mainly asking the OP to confirm that this was actually what they wanted; I've converted it to an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

`a = [s.encode() for s in a]` or `a = list(map(str.encode, a))` will both do the conversion you describe.

That said, your strings are two hexadecimal digits each, so it would make more sense to encode them as one byte each, rather than encoding the actual hexadecimal digits. To do this, you can write `a = [bytes.fromhex(s) for s in a]` or `a = list(map(bytes.fromhex, a))`.

If you want the bytes in the list as a single `bytes` object instead of a list of individual bytes, you can write `a = bytes.fromhex(''.join(a))`.