# TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '\t\x10\x03è\x00\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s0'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using this python code to control my 2F gripper but I am getting the error Type error and sometimes communication port error. This is my code:

```
import serial

import time

import binascii

ser = serial.Serial(port='COM8',baudrate=9600,timeout=1,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

counter = 0

while counter < 1:

    counter = counter + 1

    ser.write("\x09\x10\x03\xE8\x00\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x73\x30")

    data_raw = ser.readline()

    print(data_raw)

    data = binascii.hexlify(data_raw)

    print ("Response 1 ", data)

    time.sleep(0.01)

 

ser.write("\x09\x03\x07\xD0\x00\x01\x85\xCF")

data_raw = ser.readline()

print(data_raw)

data = binascii.hexlify(data_raw)

print ("Response 2 ", data)

time.sleep(1)

 

while(True):

    print ("Close gripper")

    ser.write("\x09\x10\x03\xE8\x00\x03\x06\x09\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\x42\x29")

    data_raw = ser.readline()

    print(data_raw)

    data = binascii.hexlify(data_raw)

    print ("Response 3 ", data)

    time.sleep(2)

 

print ("Open gripper")

ser.write("\x09\x10\x03\xE8\x00\x03\x06\x09\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\x72\x19")

data_raw = ser.readline()

print(data_raw)

data = binascii.hexlify(data_raw)

print ("Response 4 ", data)

time.sleep(2)
```

Error I received:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-830d10cd2151> in <module>
     13     counter = counter + 1
     14 
---> 15     ser.write("\x09\x10\x03\xE8\x00\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x73\x30")
     16 
     17     data_raw = ser.readline()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py in write(self, data)
    308             #~ raise TypeError('expected %s or bytearray, got %s' % (bytes, type(data)))
    309         # convert data (needed in case of memoryview instance: Py 3.1 io lib), ctypes doesn't like memoryview
--> 310         data = to_bytes(data)
    311         if data:
    312             #~ win32event.ResetEvent(self._overlapped_write.hEvent)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py in to_bytes(seq)
     63         return seq.tobytes()
     64     elif isinstance(seq, unicode):
---> 65         raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
     66     else:
     67         # handle list of integers and bytes (one or more items) for Python 2 and 3

TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '\t\x10\x03è\x00\x03\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s0'
```

Comment: Please include in your post the full traceback error.

Comment: This is the error I received:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)