# How to convert plain text in segmented chunks (Bytes) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-segmentation, text-segmentation

Is there a simple way to convert plain text into a segmented array of chunks in python? Each chunk should be for example 16 Bytes. If the last part of the plain text is smaller than 16 Bytes it should can be filled in a smaller chunk.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to convert string to bytes in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this function. What I am looking for is not only that but the segmentation in chunks by bytes. There is probabily already a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to achieve the same without external library then you could use bytes or bytesarray.

```
text = 'some text to convert in the chunks'
bin_str = bytes(text.encode('utf-8'))
n = 16 #no. of bytes for chunks    
chunks = [bin_str[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(bin_str), n)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Didn't knew that lists in python consider the fact that the last part is a overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chunks` method in the `funcy` library. An example would be:

```
import funcy

text = 'samplestringwithletters'
btext = text.encode('utf-8')

chunked_text = list(funcy.chunks(3,btext))
print(chunked_text)
```

Which yields:

```
[b'sam', b'ple', b'str', b'ing', b'wit', b'hle', b'tte', b'rs']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didn't knew that python copes with overflow in index...