# how to deal with that the parameter which is string but we input with bytes type

Tags: python, decode, encode

make a instance of numbers and string.
atoi() converts the string argument str to an integer.So how to converts bytes argument to string in python?
such as

```py
import sys
string = sys.argv[1]
print(string)
```

```py
python2 test.py "\000\000\000"
```

with the result of "\000\000\000" which makes no sense, but I want to converts it to '\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3
does this help?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? ``'\x00\x00\x00'`` and ``"\000\000\000"`` are the exact same string. ``sh test.py "\000\000\000"`` runs the Python code *as a shell script* which is just bogus.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am sorry that I have some wrong with my question above, and I have amended it.And I have got what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to decode the representation of a string. But you are not passing a correct representation because the quotes have been *eaten* by the shell. If you do, you will be able to use `literal_eval` to convert a representation. Demo (I have added the length of the string to make sure of what it really is:

```
import sys
import ast
string = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1])
print(len(string), repr(string))
```

You can then type:

```
python test.py '"\000\000\000"'
```

to get:

```
3 '\x00\x00\x00'
```