# How to convert a string to bytes exactly?

Tags: python, byte

I need the a string to be converted to bytes exactly as it is, so it would look like b and binascii.hexlify() would be the same for both a and b. Best way to do it? Python 3.10.0

```
a = "\x8e"
b = b'\x8e'
print(bytes(a, 'utf-8')) # b'\xc2\x8e'
print(b) # b'\x8e'
print(binascii.hexlify(bytes(a, 'utf-8'))) # b'c28e'
print(binascii.hexlify(b)) # b'8e'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3 - `my_str_as_bytes = str.encode(my_str)`

Comment: `\x8e` is outside of the ASCII range of 7 bits. This means it is a matter of encodings and code pages how this translates to bytes. This is why strings and bytes got separated in Python 3. Use the right on for your purpose (bytes)!

Comment: It makes b'\xc2\x8e', I want it to be b'\x8e'. Also, why does it add \xc2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = r'\x8e'
exec('my_string = b"' + a + '"')
print(my_string)
```

That does it.