# Python: Convert String into Bytestring

Tags: python, string, utf-8, decode

I want to decode a string, which is already encoded in UTF-8

```
"\x6d\xc3\xbc\x6c\x6c\x65\x72\x20\x69\x73\x74\x20\x63\x6f\x6f\x6c\x21"
```

I cannot find a way to decode a string without getting such a error message
`text_utf8 = text_utf8.decode("utf-8") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Is there a way to force a string to decode?

EDIT: I can´t use a Bytestring because my program imports a string out of a text file

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65874499/9760731

Comment: How are you reading the string from a file? Show your code. It should use `open(filename, encoding='utf8')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bytes function

```
byte_string = bytes(text_utf8, "utf-8")
decoded_string = byte_string.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This is just roundtripping without change. You'll get `text_utf8 == decoded_string` for any input.