# Convert a string value like 'Apple' into an integer value for faster joins

Tags: python, sql

Is there a way in SQL/Python where a string value such as 'Apple' can be computed to a unique integer value?

I've thought of using the letters of the alphabet and their position to create a cypher, however this will likely be very resource intensive if I end up having to produce said integer value using a string/substring function. I'm not aware of any built in functions that can do that.

I'm looking to extract billions of words, which will then be joined to a dimension table containing a few hundred words and want to be able to do it at speed. My thinking is that I can maintain a pre-processed table with only the integer value then match against my dimension table when needed.

Any thoughts or pointers are much appreciated

Comment: Strings are already represented as bytes under the hood. If you need the string object as bytes, you can use any one of: `b'my_string'` (prefix the string with the character `b`), `bytes('my_string', 'utf-8')` (note that you need to specify an encoding such as `'utf-8'` when using the `bytes()` function), or `'my_string'.encode()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3) for more details.

Comment: Furthermore, you can get the decimal representative of the byte object, which sounds like it would be in the ballpart of what you are after: `int.from_bytes(yourstring.encode())`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, jarlh I'm using SQL Server 2019 and Also Azure Synapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python gives several built-in hash functions, you can use `hash` function to create unique value for the sting

```
s_value = 'Apple'
h_value = hash(s_value)
print(h_value) # prints 1648332712215971780
```

or you can use libraries like `hashlib` to generate hash values

```
import hashlib

s_value = 'Apple'
h_object = hashlib.sha256(s_value.encode())
h_value = int(h_object.hexdigest(), 16)
print(h_value)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but is joining on a hash value faster than integer or string. My goal is to get the maximum speed in not only conversion to an integer, but also for the subsequent join